# How to show a second-tabbarview instead of first-tabbarview in TabBarApplication?

Tags: iphone, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am doing a reader application in iPhone which have a loginpage the login page is the firsttabbarview ,so the user needs to login sucessfully to enter the mainpage,that is the second-tabbarview.I want to know how to show the mainpage in first instead of showing the loginpage i.e. the firsttabbarview? Is that possible? I have done it in `didfinishlaunching` but no navigation is workable in the mainpage.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use selectedViewController property of UITabViewController...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi Stackiphone,

> For open second tab directly you can done with
>   **tabbarController.selectedIndex** property of your tabbarController. 
>   Set this before you load tabbar on your window.

So for secondIndex have to set with **1**

Comment: haii,yaarr.so i nee to put tabbarController.selectedIndex  = 2 in didfinishlaunching right?

Comment: i put this but again goes to firsttabbar view  tabController.selectedIndex =2;
[window addSubview:tabController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: tabController.selectedIndex =1; for second tab

Answer (score 0):

Select your mainpage's viewcontroller in the Class in Identity Inspector and give NIB name as your mainpage's nib in Attribute Inspector to show firsttabbarview.